# react-select does not auto scroll to the selected option

Tags: reactjs, react-select

How can i use react-select to scroll to the selected option?

```
<Select
              matchProp='label'
              classes={classes}
              inputId="react-select-single"
              TextFieldProps={{
                InputLabelProps: {
                  htmlFor: 'react-select-single',
                  shrink: true,
                },
                disableUnderline: true
              }}
              options={options}
              components={components}
              value={single}
              onChange={handleChangeSingle}
            />
```

Comment: Have you looked in this thread? there is active conversation. https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3648

Comment: @Kote yes i have and the only answer there is to downgrade to v2

Answer (score 1):

You can use the react-select property,

```
      menuShouldScrollIntoView={true}
```

Thank you.